# Shell command and spaces

Tags: vb.net, console-application

How I want to apply this command via my VB.NET application:

```
Shell("Reg add HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Restrictions /v NoNavBar /t  REG_DWORD /d 1 /f", vbHidden)
```

This code can't be done through `CMD` because there's a space in Internet Explorer, so in `cmd` we put `" "` Before and after the space place `,` so it becomes `"HKCU ..."`, but if I try to do this in VB.net it says *`Comma or valid expression excepted`* ,

How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Use double double quotes in the string to embed double quotes.

```
Shell("Reg add ""HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Toolbars\Restrictions"" /v NoNavBar /t  REG_DWORD /d 1 /f", vbHidden)
```

But there is a much better way of doing this.  The .NET Library has a [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class and a [RegistryKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey.aspx) class so there is no need to call an external function to add a new registry value.

Comment: Ok thank I will try this . And I will search about the class. Thank you shf